# springboot @EnableConfigurationProperties not work

Tags: java, spring-boot, aspectj

I want to read application.properties using

```
@EnableConfigurationProperties and @ConfigurationProperties.
```

Here are the codes:

```
TraceLogProperties.java:

@ConfigurationProperties("tracelog")
public @Data class TraceLogProperties {

    private Boolean enable;

    ...some other fields.

}

TraceLogAutoConfigure.java:

@Configuration @Slf4j
@EnableConfigurationProperties(TraceLogProperties.class)
@AutoConfigureAfter(WebConfig.class)
public class TraceLogAutoConfigure {

    private @Autowired TraceLogProperties traceLogProperties;

    @ConditionalOnProperty(name = "tracelog.repository.enable", havingValue = "true")
    @Bean("repositoryInterceptor")
    public Interceptor repositoryInterceptor() {
        log.info("init repositoryInterceptor...");
        return new TraceLogInterceptor(this.traceLogProperties.getRepository());
    }

    @ConditionalOnProperty(name = "tracelog.service.enable", havingValue = "true")
    @Bean("serviceInterceptor")
    public Interceptor serviceInterceptor() {
        log.info("init serviceInterceptor...");
        return new TraceLogInterceptor(this.traceLogProperties.getService());
    }

    @ConditionalOnProperty(name = "tracelog.controller.enable", havingValue = "true")
    @Bean("controllerInterceptor")
    public Interceptor controllerInterceptor() {
        log.info("init controllerInterceptor...");
        return new TraceLogInterceptor(this.traceLogProperties.getController());
    }

    @ConditionalOnProperty(name = "tracelog.repository.enable", havingValue = "true")
    public @Bean Advisor repositoryAdvisor() {
        log.info("init repositoryAdvisor...");
        AspectJExpressionPointcut pointcut = new AspectJExpressionPointcut();
        pointcut.setExpression(this.traceLogProperties.getRepository().getPointcut());
        return new DefaultPointcutAdvisor(pointcut, repositoryInterceptor());
    }

    @ConditionalOnProperty(name = "tracelog.service.enable", havingValue = "true")
    public @Bean Advisor serviceAdvisor() {
        log.info("init serviceAdvisor...");
        AspectJExpressionPointcut pointcut = new AspectJExpressionPointcut();
        pointcut.setExpression(this.traceLogProperties.getService().getPointcut());
        return new DefaultPointcutAdvisor(pointcut, serviceInterceptor());
    }

    @ConditionalOnProperty(name = "tracelog.controller.enable", havingValue = "true")
    public @Bean Advisor controllerAdvisor() {
        log.info("init controllerAdvisor...");
        AspectJExpressionPointcut pointcut = new AspectJExpressionPointcut();
        pointcut.setExpression(this.traceLogProperties.getController().getPointcut());
        return new DefaultPointcutAdvisor(pointcut, controllerInterceptor());
    }
}
```

Then, when i start the application, it always occurred NullPointerException on

```
pointcut.setExpression(this.traceLogProperties.getController().getPointcut());
```

By debugging, i found that `this.traceLogProperties` is null. But, if i delete any two advisors, it will be will become normal, like this:

```
@Configuration @Slf4j
@EnableConfigurationProperties(TraceLogProperties.class)
@AutoConfigureAfter(WebConfig.class)
public class TraceLogAutoConfigure {

    private @Autowired TraceLogProperties traceLogProperties;

    @ConditionalOnProperty(name = "tracelog.repository.enable", havingValue = "true")
    @Bean("repositoryInterceptor")
    public Interceptor repositoryInterceptor() {
        log.info("init repositoryInterceptor...");
        return new TraceLogInterceptor(this.traceLogProperties.getRepository());
    }

    @ConditionalOnProperty(name = "tracelog.service.enable", havingValue = "true")
    @Bean("serviceInterceptor")
    public Interceptor serviceInterceptor() {
        log.info("init serviceInterceptor...");
        return new TraceLogInterceptor(this.traceLogProperties.getService());
    }

    @ConditionalOnProperty(name = "tracelog.controller.enable", havingValue = "true")
    @Bean("controllerInterceptor")
    public Interceptor controllerInterceptor() {
        log.info("init controllerInterceptor...");
        return new TraceLogInterceptor(this.traceLogProperties.getController());
    }

    @ConditionalOnProperty(name = "tracelog.controller.enable", havingValue = "true")
    public @Bean Advisor controllerAdvisor() {
        log.info("init controllerAdvisor...");
        AspectJExpressionPointcut pointcut = new AspectJExpressionPointcut();
        pointcut.setExpression(this.traceLogProperties.getController().getPointcut());
        return new DefaultPointcutAdvisor(pointcut, controllerInterceptor());
    }
}
```

Any idea? What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

Try marking your `TraceLogProperties` as a component:

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties("tracelog")
public @Data class TraceLogProperties {
```

Comment: Works for me. Make sure that the class you autowire your properties to is a service or some other type of component. Apparently, non-annotated POJOs won't work. From the service you can just get your properties and pass them to your POJO constructors. Also, no need for EnableConfigurationProperties if you are setting your properties class as a component